# Pipe function argument type is inferred as any

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, typescript-generics

Based on the examples in [Higher order function type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30215) I tested, how TS resolves function composition types in a `pipe` function. `pipe`:

```
declare function pipe<A extends any[], B, C>(
    ab: (...args: A) => B, bc: (b: B) => C): (...args: A) => C;
```

These are the functions passed to the pipe:

```
declare function list<T>(a: T): T[];
declare function box<V>(x: V): { value: V };
declare function numberBox(x: number[]): { value: number[] }
```

The PR example with the generic `box` function properly enforces the argument type of `listBox(1)` to be `number`:

```
const listBox = pipe(list, box);  // T is retained
const x1 = listBox(1); // ... argument properly inferred to  number here
```

But when I use a non-generic `number[]` box function, the argument gets `any` type:

```
const listNumberBox = pipe(list, numberBox)
const x21 = listNumberBox(1) // argument has any type
const x22 = listNumberBox("asdfasd") // this shouldn't be possible :/
```

I would assume that inference of a concrete type actually is even "easier" than of a generic type (?), so

1.) why is the argument type of last example inferred to `any`?

2.) How do I can change the function signature of `pipe` to enforce all types properly?

Comment: Looks like [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30727#issuecomment-479657502) is related; it's as close to an answer to 1 as I can find right now

Comment: Thank you, the link is indeed very helpful. At least there seems to be consensus with TS team, that `pipe` & co. still have typing problems in their classic form `pipe(fn1, fn2,..)(x)`, so there is hope for improvement. If you want: I would accept the issue hint as answer.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'll write that up as an answer.  Still I wish I found something more definitive... since it seems like the compiler should be able to instantiate the `T` in `f<T>(x: T): T[]` as `number` if the return type matches `number[]`.